# Unresolved external symbol _declspec(dllimport)

Tags: c++, dll, enums, console-application, dllimport

I've created an DLL for my Console Application in Visual Studio.
In my DLL I have a Class named Dialog_MainMenu with has a *.cpp file and a *.h file.

**Following error message**:

> Error 9   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol
>   "__declspec(dllimport) public: static enum
>   Dialog_MainMenu::GAME_STATES Dialog_MainMenu::CurrentGameState"
>   (_*imp*?CurrentGameState@Dialog_MainMenu@@2W4GAME_STATES@1@A) C:\Users\Kevin\Desktop\c++
>   projects\development_testing\The Intense
>   Adventure\Dialogs\Dialog_MainMenu.obj Dialogs

Which I kinda don't understand. This only occured when I added an enum to my prototype in my header file.

**Header file**:

```
#ifdef DIALOG_MAINMENU_EXPORTS
#define DIALOG_MAINMENU_API __declspec(dllexport) 
#else
#define DIALOG_MAINMENU_API __declspec(dllimport) 
#endif

class Dialog_MainMenu {
public:
    static DIALOG_MAINMENU_API enum GAME_STATES {
        MAINMENU, GAME, OPTIONS, CREDITS, QUIT
    };
    static DIALOG_MAINMENU_API GAME_STATES CurrentGameState;
    DIALOG_MAINMENU_API GAME_STATES GetState();
};
```

(Don't know if issue lies here, so I'll just add it)
**cpp file in general**:

```
//Get state
Dialog_MainMenu::GAME_STATES Dialog_MainMenu::GetState() {
 // Code..
}

//Switching state
Dialog_MainMenu::CurrentGameState = Dialog_MainMenu::GAME_STATES::GAME;
```

I would really appreciate, any help or atleast some advice, where I can learn more about this problem.

Comment: did you reference the .lib file ?

Comment: I sure did. I even triple checked.

Comment: Can you add the linking command used to your question?

Comment: Do you mean the Addtional Include Directiories? I don't quite understand what you mean. Im kinda new to C++.

Comment: No, I mean the full linker command that the IDE invoked to produce that linking error in your question. It should be somewhere in the buildlog.

Comment: Note, you don't need `static` and `DIALOG_MAINMENU_API` in `enum GAME_STATES`.

Comment: Can't seem to find that log.. :/
- Also, I've tried to remove the static and DIALOG_... Same error message.

Comment: Try looking in your project folder location. Check its subdirectories like debug, release etc.

Comment: I have a couple of files named things like link.command, link.read, etc.. Which contains nothing in it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to define the static member in your cpp file in global scope.

```
Dialog_MainMenu::GAME_STATES Dialog_MainMenu::CurrentGameState;
```

Alternatively, you can also assign it some initial value.

```
Dialog_MainMenu::GAME_STATES Dialog_MainMenu::CurrentGameState = Dialog_MainMenu::GAME_STATES::GAME;
```

**EDIT**:

> I've created an DLL for my Console Application in Visual Studio. In my DLL I have a Class named Dialog_MainMenu with has a *.cpp file and a *.h file.

OK - when you compile the dll - you are exporting the types. So, you need to `define` the static member in `.cpp` file of the dll. You also need to make sure that you have enabled the definition of `DIALOG_MAINMENU_EXPORTS` in compiler settings. This will make sure types are exported.

Now, when you link the console application with the dll - you will `#include` dll's header  and dont enable any definition of `DIALOG_MAINMENU_EXPORTS` in compiler settings (just leave the settings default). This will make the compiler understand that now you are importing the types from your dll into console application.

I hope its clear now.

Comment: And where is that? Can't seem to find the place, Where i've put the following line you typed at first.

Comment: Just like you `declare` methods in `.h` file and `define` them in `.cpp` - you also need to `define` the `static` members. You can put that line of code right above `Dialog_MainMenu::GAME_STATES Dialog_MainMenu::GetState() {`

Comment: That just give me an error: definition of dllimport static data member not allowed

Comment: are you trying to import or export types?

Answer (score 5):

Check if you added reference to your project with .dll
(It's solved my problem)
Right click on project > Add > Reference > (project with your .dll)

Comment: Even 6 years later people still find this questions
Probably it will be helpful for someone!

Comment: still helps today

Comment: Yup still helps

Answer (score 2):

There is a problem with exporting static class members:

**[If you declare a static data member within a class definition as dllexport, a definition must occur somewhere within the same program (as with nonclass external linkage).](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/81h27t8c%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)**

But what I usually do is use an access method. Static function methods are linked fine.

```
//.h file
class Dialog_MainMenu {
public:
    static DIALOG_MAINMENU_API enum GAME_STATES {
        MAINMENU, GAME, OPTIONS, CREDITS, QUIT
    };
    static GAME_STATES CurrentGameState;
    DIALOG_MAINMENU_API GAME_STATES GetState();

   static DIALOG_MAINMENU_API  GAME_STATES& GetCurrentState();
};

//.cpp file

GAME_STATES& Dialog_MainMenu ::GetCurrentState()
{

return CurrentGameState;
}
```